# What do we call a rainwater pond?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call a small pond of rainwater that usually appears on the street after rainfall?

Can we call them a pond?

Comment: I think you're talking about ***[puddles](http://onelook.com/?w=puddle&ls=a)***; *ponds* are much larger and, e.g., can have fish in them.

Comment: A citizen walks in the pond caused by heavy rain: http://www.gettyimages.it/evento/rainstorms-pour-in-hubei-651910955#citizen-walks-in-the-pond-caused-by-heavy-rain-on-july-4-2016-in-picture-id544838238

Comment: @Josh61, that seems more like a flood

Comment: Should we answer a question that would take 5 seconds on http://translate.google.com ? I am assuming here OP is non-native speaker.

Comment: @k1eran ~ be careful there k1eran, lest someone call you a dirty bigot and exclusionist :)  I've had my fair share of that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mean this sort of thing...

[image: Puddle]

... then it's a **puddle.**

By "Raindog808" from [a post by Melina Maniscalco](http://photographyblogger.net/21-relaxing-puddle-pictures/). Plenty more images there, too.

> A small pool of liquid, especially of rainwater on the ground:
>    ‘splashing through deep puddles’
>    *figurative* ‘a little puddle of light’
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puddle)

Comment: Any passing doctors would do well not to step in them. They may find them rather deep.

Comment: But when it's raining cats and dogs you have to be careful to not step in a poodle.